# NPM Link Vs. requiring using path

Tags: node.js, express, npm

[NPM link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) seems cool, but what are the differences between NPM link and requiring the module by giving the path? Could you please elaborate the advantageous of each?

When you use npm link you can require it like:

```
var foo = require("foo");
```

but if you use the path, you require it like:

```
var foo = require("./lib/foo");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Npm link is useful if you are developing some node_module which has dependency to other standalone node_module you are also developing simultaneously (which you then may upload to the npm when it is ready / releasable). Using this setup you will always get the freshest version of "other module" without need to push releases to npm.

It is better than using relative dependencies because relative paths can be individual (per developer), but npm link works as if it was required from npm (located in node_modules folder).

Conclusion: I usually use relative dependencies inside of module itself to require other files and npm link to specify dependencies between simultaneously developed standalone modules.